# Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal return statement in recursive function

Tags: javascript, recursion, return

I'm getting an illegal return statement in the line of my code near the bottom that says: return points

```
createPoints(x, y, length, depth, angle, points)
{
  if(depth > 0)
  {
    //draws line
    points.push((x + length) * Math.sin(angle));
    points.push((y + length) * Math.cos(angle));

    //draw left branch
    angle += Math.PI / 4;
    createPoints(treeString, (x + length/2) * Math.sin(angle), (y + length/2) * Math.cos(angle), depth - 1, points);

    //goes back
    points.push(x);
    points.push(y);

    //draw right branch
    angle -= Math.PI / 2;
    createPoints(treeString, (x + length/2) * Math.sin(angle), (y + length/2) * Math.cos(angle), depth - 1, points);
    return points;
  }
  return;
}
```

the function is supposed to plot points in an array for a fractal tree to use in webgl. I'm not sure why I'm getting my error and unfortunately, neither my professor nor TA know either.

Comment: Since you can only use `return` within a [Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions), you *must* declare `createPoints` as such, i.e `function createPoints(x, y, length, depth, angle, points) { // function body ... } `. Check the MDN link about functions and to see alternative ways to declare one.

Comment: Can you show the full error (a screenshot, if necessary) and more context for the code?

Comment: Oh, is this code just at the top level? You’re trying to use a shorthand that only works in classes and object literals. There needs to be some kind of declaration involved, like @NikKyriakides said.

Comment: can you share the whole code so that we can debug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing function keyword for your function name
try below pattern, it will help you .

```
 function createPoints () {} 

let createPoints = () => {}
```